# Blender 2.8.2 Hair simulation - Pin hair to itself

Tags: particles, hair

I'm attempting to create a braid that I can enable Hair Dynamics for to simulate it as opposed to animating by hand. So far I've managed to create a braid with three hairs, each with simple children:

[image: braid1]

(This is just a test so it's obviously not great, but that's not the issue.)

I've enabled Hair Dynamics and the hair flings around as it should. The issue now is that the three strands separate from each other as they're moving, especially towards the bottom. The structure and stiffness parameters of the simulation seems insufficient to get them to stay together.

In real life most long/loose braids have a band or loop of some kind at the bottom that holds them together. Is there a way to do something similar in Blender, where the strands are "pinned" to each other at a certain point? Or is there a better way to accomplish this?

One thing that didn't work was using the `Weight` tool in Particle Edit mode, but increasing the weight at the ends seems to hold the points relative to the root position, not relative to each other.

(I would upload a gif of this not working, but Stack Exchange doesn't seem to want to let me.)

As a clarifying example, what I'm trying to accomplish is essentially the small knot at the end of this braid (Anna from *Frozen*).

[image: anna_braid]

Answer (score 0):

You can try the free hairguide addon https://blenderartists.org/t/particle-hair-from-meshes-bezier-curves-nurbs/1154670 . It can create hair guides inside a mesh while following the exact direction.Then you can use bevel radius or a curve as bevel to create each braid shape.It's easy to adjust the thickness using  ALT + S.

[image]